# How do you configure the title, description and license in Springfox Swagger UI?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

When you start Swagger UI with Springfox in a Spring Boot app, it looks like this:

[image]

How do you configure the title and description ("Api Documentation") and the license (Apache 2.0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set these values by passing the [ApiInfo](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.6.0/index.html?springfox/documentation/service/ApiInfo.html) object to your docket.

```
new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    ...
    .apiInfo(new ApiInfo(...))
    ...
```

ApiInfo's constructor accepts several details about your API. In you case, you should look at title, description, and license parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger config class (Spring boot):

```
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Demo Test API")
                .description("Demo test API task")
                .license("© 2021 by my")
                .build();
    }

}
```